# file_put_contents & file_get_contents speed

Tags: php, performance, file-get-contents

I am executing two functions after each other.

function 1 executes a for loop 10 times and add some values which it retreives from another server to an array.
After this I retrieve an txt file with file_get_contents and json_decode it.
I merge the file_get_contents array with the for loop array and do a json_encode and a file_put_contents to a txt file.

function 2 is retrieving the last line from the same txt file.
I am using json_decode and array_pop for this.
THen I return the last value of the txt file.
AFter this I remove the last line. So each time if you execute this function it returns the last line and removes it.

I execute them like this in index.php:

```
if(is_null(function2($account))){
    function1($account, 10);
    var_dump(function2($account));

}else{
    var_dump(function2($account));
}
```

But for some reason if the file is empty and function2 (array_pop) should return null. function1 kicks in and it generates a new pool and adding the new lines to the txt file.
If this is done I again execute function2. So this should show a new line right?
But it doesn't. It just returns null. Even when I repopulated the txt file before executing function2. Can anybody tell me why this is?

Thanks.

Comment: what do function1 and function2 look like?

Comment: Question title mentions speed. How does speed relate to your problem?

Comment: Question title and performance tag is misleading.

Comment: Cause it may be a speed thing since function2 gets executed after the txt file is populated again. So why does it return null then sometimes if the file populated?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario It's a *race condition*. *Racing* == *Speed*.

Comment: Ah, alright. I'd say it's impossible to get a race condition per-se in a single threaded language like PHP. But, of course, if all the script instances read and write *the same* file at the same time (detail we don't know), all sort of bad things can happen.

Comment: Isn't it that function2 should wait for function1 to finish then?
Cause it looks like it executes function2 directly simultaneously with function1? This results in function1 populating the file while function2 is trying to read it which results in null?